# How install Python 3.8.3(Global) and a Python 3.7.3(local)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, compatibility, python-3.8

I need Python 3.8.3 (Global) for a project, the latest version and Python 3.7.3 (Local) to use pyautogui, to convert a .py file to .exe, could someone please tell you how to do this, or if there is any alternative. Thank you very much for your attention and cooperation.

Comment: Have you looked into virtual environments?  This allows multiple Python installation to sit happily side-by-side.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Conda and create a new environment with a specific python version.
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/

Comment: virtualenv could be the solution for you.